# Sparkline in Leaflet popup/label within Shiny using leafletProxy

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, popup, sparklines

I'm trying to add a sparkline in a leaflet label within a shiny app. I'm able to do this when not using `leafletProxy`, but can't figure out how to make it work when using `leafletProxy` (which need to use for my actual app).

See below example. For leaflet without proxy, the markers show up but the label is blank.

```r
# Some code adapted from here:
# http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/33db1fb9e64257ef7149754bdff0b2e0
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(sparkline)

as.character.htmlwidget <- function(x, ...) {
  htmltools::HTML(
    htmltools:::as.character.shiny.tag.list(
      htmlwidgets:::as.tags.htmlwidget(
        x
      ),
      ...
    )
  )
}

add_deps <- function(dtbl, name, pkg = name) {
  tagList(
    dtbl,
    htmlwidgets::getDependency(name, pkg)
  )
}

# Make dummy data --------------------------------------------------------------
data <- data.frame(lat = runif(100),
                   lon = runif(100),
                   value = runif(100),
                   id = rep(1:10, 10)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(l_spark = spk_chr(value,
                              lineColor = 'orange', 
                              fillColor = 'orange',
                              chartRangeMin = 0,
                              chartRangeMax = 8,
                              tooltipChartTitle = "COVID-19 Cases",
                              highlightLineColor = 'orange', 
                              highlightSpotColor = 'orange'),
            lat = mean(lat),
            lon = mean(lon))


# UI ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(6, align = "center",
           strong("No Proxy"),
           uiOutput("map_no_proxy")
    ),
    column(6, align = "center",
           strong("With Proxy"),
           leafletOutput("map_with_proxy")
    )
  )
)

# Server ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Map with Proxy --------------------------------------
  output$map_with_proxy <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles()
    
  })
  
  observe({
    
    leafletProxy("map_with_proxy", data = data) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        ~lon, ~lat,
        label = ~lapply(l_spark, HTML)
      ) %>%
      onRender(
        "function(el,x) {
         this.on('tooltipopen', function() {HTMLWidgets.staticRender();})
         }
      ") %>%
      add_deps("sparkline") %>%
      browsable()
    
  })
  
  # Map without Proxy --------------------------------------
  output$map_no_proxy <- renderUI({
    
    leaflet(data = data) %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        ~lon, ~lat,
        label = ~lapply(l_spark, HTML)
      ) %>%
      onRender(
        "function(el,x) {
         this.on('tooltipopen', function() {HTMLWidgets.staticRender();})
         }
      ") %>%
      add_deps("sparkline") %>%
      browsable()
    
  })
  
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `onRender` function is used to call Javascript code when the leaflet is rendered (that is in your `renderLeaflet` function). `leafletProxy` on the other hand does not re-render the leaflet, but allows to modify the existing leaflet. This is done in order to avoid re-running potentially heavy code.

One option is to put the `onRender` into the `renderLeaflet` function like this:

```r
output$map_with_proxy <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      onRender(
        "function(el,x) {
         this.on('tooltipopen', function() {HTMLWidgets.staticRender();})
         }
      ")
    
  })
```